# Will More vCPU's and RAM Help Protect Against Some Smaller Scale DDoS Attacks?

Tags: ddos, cpu

**Obviously having more vCPU's (virtual CPU's) and more RAM by them self won't be able to alone help stop and/or prevent a DDoS attack**, but let's say after a DDoS attack is finished and/or slowing down would having more vCPU's and RAM dedicated to a server help recover from the attack faster?

Comment: It depends. Some attacks work by tying up ports on the machine by opening sockets and then sending nothing. More CPU and RAM may not help with this. But in a “cloud” environment a load balancer might help, even with only one machine behind it.